# Google Tag Manager null container

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to follow what is described here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#init and this is what I have:

```
TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);


    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault("GTM-XXXXXX",
                    R.raw.gtm);


    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            Log.d("NICK","Inside onResult...") ;
            if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");

                return;
            }

            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());

        }
    }, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


    Log.d("NICK","Value: "+container.getString("test_value));
```

and what is happening is a `NullPointerException` at the above `Log` line because `container` is null:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.app/com.nick.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.Container.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.Container.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I enabled logging for google tag manager and I get what appears to me to be "normal" behavior:

```
05-16 11:53:04.865 22585-22662/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: Deleted 0 expired items
05-16 11:53:04.867 22585-22585/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: Attempting to load a container from the resource ID 2131034112 (com.nick.app:raw/gtm)
05-16 11:53:04.888 22585-22585/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: The container was successfully loaded from the resource (using JSON file format)
05-16 11:53:04.903 22585-22664/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: Attempting to load resource from disk
05-16 11:53:04.925 22585-22664/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-XXXXXXX delay=40721307
05-16 11:53:04.925 22585-22664/com.nick.app D/GoogleTagManager: Setting previous container version: NQ$0
05-16 11:53:04.929 22585-22664/com.nick.app V/GoogleTagManager: The Disk resource was successfully read.
```

and also my Log Statement inside `onResult` is never shown which would explain why `container` is null as that is the only location any initialization would occur. Shouldn't `onResult` be reached and `container` be initialized? I'm slightly confused as to how this should be implemented correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the `ContainerHolder` occurs asynchronously so it has not been assigned a value at the point where you are currently trying to log a value from it.

The site you linked to has the following documentation about `onResult()`.

> The onResult method will be called as soon as one of the following
>   happens:
>
> 1. a saved container is loaded
> 2. if there is no saved container, a network container is loaded
> 3. the specified timeout occurs

This means that you cannot access the `container` until after `onResult(...)` has been called since that is where it is assigned a value. You can move the log statement into that method to test retrieving a value and do whatever else you need to do with the container at that point.

```
public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
    ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
    container = containerHolder.getContainer();

    Log.d("NICK","Inside onResult...") ;
    if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
        return;
    }

    ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
    containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());

    // do whatever you want with the container at this point
    Log.d("NICK","Value: " + container.getString("test_value));
}
```